# Как парсить путь url?

Tags: python-3.x

Мне необходимо из ссылки по типу:

```
https://reshak.ru/otvet/otvet_txt.php?otvet1=/spotlight8/images/SongSheets/module8/3
```

Достать фрагменты

```
SongSheets
module8
3
```

Дело в том, что этих ссылок очень много и мне нужно по шаблону достать фрагменты для каждой такой ссылки. Не могу понять как это реализовать. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте `'https://reshak.ru/otvet/otvet_txt.php?otvet1=/spotlight8/images/SongSheets/module8/3'.split('/')[-3:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать библиотеку urllib (urlparse в Python 2)

```
# python 3
from urllib.parse import urlparse
# python2
# from urlparse import urlparse

urls = ["https://reshak.ru/otvet/otvet_txt.php?otvet1=/spotlight8/images/SongSheets/module8/3&var1=helloworld",
        "https://reshak.ru/otvet/otvet_txt.php?otvet2=/spotlight5/images/SongSheets/module5/3&var2=byeworld",
        ]

allResponses = [] # массив со всеми найденными ответами
for url in urls:
    o = urlparse(url)
    params = o.query
    # разделяем параметры друг от друга
    params = params.split("&")

    for param in params:
        if "=" in param:
            key, value = param.split("=")
            # если в ключе содержится "otvet" - добавляем в allResponses
            if "otvet" in key:
                allResponses.append(
                    value.split('/')[-3:]
                )
                # тут можно прервать цикл, если уверены, что в URL больше нету otvet'ов
                # break

print(allResponses)
```